# Given a $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ find $D \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x)=D(x+1)-D(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Suppose you have a function $f(x)$, $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ now you want to find a function $D_f(x)$, $D_f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x) = D_f(x+1)-D_f(x),  \forall x \in \mathbb{N}$.

Example: Given $f(x) = x$ we can find $D_f(x) = \frac{x^2-x}{2} + C$ with any constant $C$.

---

#### Properties I found so far

Define $P(f) = D_f$, the operator that describes the operation defined above.

#### P is linear

For $g, h$ functions $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N}$: $P(\alpha g+\beta h) = \alpha D_g + \beta D_h$

---

Is there a general solution to this problem that allows one to solve this problem for (m)any functions $f$ and describes the operator $P$?

Comment: Gosper's algorithm